# Expected a spy, but got BehaviorSubject

Tags: angular, юнит-тесты, jasmine, karma

Я пишу тест (1) для функции (2). У меня вибивает Error: Expected a spy, but got BehaviorSubject. Может есть идеи как исправить?

(1)

```
it('should call componentsOffsetService on scroll', () => {
spyOn(componentsOffsetService.onScroll, 'next');
const container = fixture.debugElement.query( By.css('.main-container'));
container.nativeElement.scroll();
fixture.detectChanges();
fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
  expect(componentsOffsetService.onScroll).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

(2)

```
public onScroll(event): void {
    this.componentsOffsetService.onScroll.next(event.target.scrollTop);
  }
```

(3) onScroll in componentsOffsetService

```
public onScroll = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
```

Comment: ты же установила спай на метод `next`, естественно жасмин его и оверрайдит, а проверяешь метод `onScroll`, нужно проверять `onScroll.next`

Comment: Если я проверяю onScroll. next у меня ошибка ERROR: 'Unhandled Promise rejection:', '<toHaveBeenCalledTimes> : Expected a spy, but got Function.